# Jump to specific folder in catalog pane using Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, python-addin

I am developing a Python add-in for ArcGIS Desktop.

As a part of this add-in there is a button that I would like to jump me to specific folder in the Catalog Window.

Is there any way to do this?